# fill in na values with `ffill` (or any other method) that increments by 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF which I want to fill in NA values.

I would like to fill it with increasing values as following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,1 ],[1, 1 ], [2, None], [3, None]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['user', 'days_unseen'])

#current behavior of ffill, leaves value the same
df['value']=df['value'].ffill()
print(df)

#desired fill - increments last value by 1
desired_data = [[1,1 ],[1, 1 ], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
desired_df = pd.DataFrame(desired_data, columns = ['user', 'days_unseen'])
print(desired_df)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for count missing values and add last non missing values by forward filling missing values:

```
df['value'] = df['days_unseen'].isna().cumsum() + df['days_unseen'].ffill()
print(df)
   user  days_unseen  value
0     1          1.0    1.0
1     1          1.0    1.0
2     2          NaN    2.0
3     3          NaN    3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an auxilliary Series to compute increasing sequences for each sequence of NaN values:

```
s = df.days_unseen.shift().loc[df.days_unseen.isna()]

s = pd.Series(data=1, index=s.index).cumsum() + s.fillna(
    method='ffill')
```

You can then use it to fill empty values in the original dataframe:

```
df.days_unseen.fillna(s, inplace=True)
```

It gives as expected:

```
   user  days_unseen
0     1          1.0
1     1          1.0
2     2          2.0
3     3          3.0
```